# Import vector graphics to inkscape

Tags: graphics, fonts, file-format, inkscape, vector-drawings

I'm producing vector graphics in my research with Maethematica and/or MATLAB, and I want to combine a few of them. I thought the best would be to use inkscape to do that, but unfortunately inkscape messes up the text in my graphics (usually the axes labels and greek glyphs, but also plain text).

This happens when I export the files in either PDF, SVG or EPS formats.

I'd really like to learn about two types of solutions:

1. Is there an easy way to fix this (install fonts etc)?

   OR
2. Is there a more suitable program than inkscape?

Comment: Are the fonts you used to create these labels system fonts that Inkscape has access to? Try creating a text label manually with Inkscape and see if you can find the fonts used by Mathematica and MATLAB. If they aren't available then this could very well be the reason why your images render incorrectly. Inkscape tries to approximate a font if it doesn't find it installed on the system. This process isn't always perfect,

Comment: @Glutanimate Thanks. The fonts that are used are (I think) what latex uses, and it's called CMR or CMBX or something of that sort. How do I install them so that inkscape has access to them?

Comment: I have similar issues with python-matplotlib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to completely solve this problem, but this is the workaround that I use at the moment:

- The `pdf2svg` package transforms a a `pdf` to `svg` by vectorizing the text *using the embedded fonts*, so it doesn't matter if inkscape has or hasn't access to these fonts.
- The downside is that after the vectorization one cannot modify the text any more. For this I use `TeXText`

Comment: `pdf2svg` looks like a handy tool and solves the font issue. However, for vector line art it is not as good as Inkscape's importer. Smooth lines (bezier, I assume), come out 'pixelalated' (with discrete steps).

Comment: See also related: [How to outline fonts in a PDF or EPS file](http://askubuntu.com/questions/309658/how-to-outline-fonts-in-a-pdf-or-eps-file/660145#660145).