# How to outline fonts in a PDF (or eps) file?

Tags: fonts, pdf, inkscape

Say, I have a PDF graphic (such a plot made with matplotlib, Mathematica or similar), which contains vector art and text. The text uses non-standard or proprietary fonts  (such Computer Modern if inline-TeX is used). The fonts are (usually) embedded and the PDF renders nicely in evince/acroread.

I'd like to edit/share the pdf without relying on those fonts, e.g. in Inkscape. Is there tool that will convert all text to paths?

- Inkscape is not suitable here because it will replace the non-standard font with "Sans".
- [pdf2svg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293033/import-vector-graphics-to-inkscape/294862#294862) has issues with line art.

Comment: Excellent question. In Inkscape you can search and replace fonts if that somehow helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use Inkscape for this.

File -> Open -> open your PDF.

A dialog "PDF Import Settings" will pop up. If you tick the checkbox "Import via Poppler", the text will be converted to symbols on importing.

If needed, you can convert symbols further to paths and edit them (but as far as the specific question here goes, namely editing/sharing the pdf without relying on the fonts, symbols work fine).